# Prove that $M_{16} / Z(M_{16}) \cong C_2 \times C_2$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, group-presentation

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Prove that $M_{16} / Z(M_{16}) \cong C_2 \times C_2$.  Where $M_{16}=\langle x, y | x^{8}=1, y^{2}=1, yx=x^{5}y\rangle$ is the modular group of order 16.

I know that $Z(M_{16})=\langle x^{2}\rangle=\{1, x^{2}, x^{4}, x^{6}\}$ and $\left( M_{16}:\langle x^{2}\rangle \right) = 4$.

I'm not sure what to do with this information to prove what I need to prove, my brain says "it's not $C_{4}$ so it must be $C_2 \times C_2$" but obviously that isn't very helpful (and probably not a correct way of thinking!).

Comment: What is the group $ M_{16} $? In any event, there are only two groups up to isomorphism of order $ 4 $, and the quotient of a non-abelian group by its center can't be cyclic, so if $ M_{16} $ is not abelian and it has center of index $ 4 $ then this quotient must be isomorphic to $ C_2 \times C_2 $.

Comment: @Starfall apologies, I've now edited the question to explain $M_{16}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given what you know about the center, quotienting this group by its center is just equivalent to enforcing the additional relation $ x^2 = 1 $ in its group presentation, in which case you get an obvious presentation of the Klein four group $ C_2 \times C_2 $ - the presentation becomes

$$ \langle x, y | x^2 = 1, \, y^2 = 1, \, xy = yx \rangle $$