# Realization of the Modulor group $M_{16}$ of order $16$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Consider the Modulor group $M_{16}$ of order $16$ given by the presentation
$$
M_{16}=\langle a,b:a^8=b^2=1,ba=ab^5\rangle
$$
Is there a known realization of $M_{16}$ by matrices?

Comment: Every finite group can be represented as matrices.  Use Cayley's theorem if need be.

Comment: To be more helpful:  is there a particular kind of matrix representation you're looking for?

Comment: 2x2 matrices can be helpful. Thanks #Randall

Comment: Are you sure that there is a *faithful* representation of this group in 2 by 2 matrices? I think that any finite subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is either cyclic or dihedral (and I don't think that M16 is dihedral), but I'm not sure about complex representations.

Comment: Title: it is "Modular group", not Modulor. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674776/prove-that-m-16-zm-16-cong-c-2-times-c-2) for the name and some useful facts.

Comment: @march But there are two conjugate faithful complex representations of degree $2$. The minimum degree of a real representation is $4$.

Comment: @march As the centre is cyclic there is a faithful irreducible representation of $M_{16}$. The character degrees have to be $1$ and $2$ because the sum of the squares is 16. Thus it must embed in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a theorem saying that a $p$-group has a faithful irreducible complex character if and only if the center is cyclic. The modular group has a cyclic center and all irreducible character has degree 1 or 2. Hence, you can represent this group by complex $2\times 2$-matrices.

To be more precise: Let $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ be a primitive $8$-th root of unity, $a=\mathrm{diag}(\zeta,\zeta^5)$ and $b=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.

Answer (score 2):

One automatic way to get a faithful matrix representation of a group is to construct the regular representation, where we assign a basis vector $v_g$ to each group element $g$, and construct the linear transformation $T_h$ of $h$ by left-multiplication by $h$, i.e.
$$
T_hv_g = v_{hg}\,.
$$
Then, one can see that
$$
T_{h_1}T_{h_2}v_g = T_{h_1}v_{h_2g} = v_{h_1h_2g} = T_{h_1h_2}v_{g}\,.
$$
Ordering the group elements $\{g_1=e, g_2, g_3, \dots, g_{16}\}$, we can construct the Cayley table, and from each column $c_j$ of the table, we can construct a corresponding permutation matrix as
$$
P_{i,c_i} = 1\,,
$$
with all other matrix elements equal to zero.

---

Here's an implementation in *Mathematica*.  Using the permutation representation from the list of [groups of order 16](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16#The_list), which is
$$
M_{16} = \langle (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 5)(3,7)\rangle\,,
$$
we can construct the group in *Mathematica* as

```
group = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{Range[8]}], Cycles[{{1, 5}, {3, 7}}]}];
```

The group multiplication table is given by

```
GroupMultiplicationTable[group] // TableForm
```

[image]

and so we can construct the set of permutation matrices via

```
matrixRep = IdentityMatrix[16][[#]] & /@ Transpose@GroupMultiplicationTable[group];
```

This set of matrices matches the group multiplication.  For example, multiplying the 2nd and third elements and finding the position of the result in the original list yields

```
PermutationProduct[elements[[2]], elements[[3]]];
First@Position[elements, %]
(* Cycles[{{1, 2, 7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4}}] *)
(* {4} )*
```

whereas multiplying the corresponding matrices yields

```
matrixRep[[2]].matrixRep[[3]];
First@Position[matrixRep, %]
(* {4} *)
```

---

If you want a list of all of the matrices, I can include them elsewhere.

---

Finally, I do not know the minimum dimension required to get a *faithful* matrix representation of this group.

Comment: Thanks @march for your answer